# PostgreSQL - Searching a text field that contains special characters

Tags: postgresql, select

I'm trying to search for the following text in a field called th.descripition.  The text is

> Previous ticket, Priority: STANDARD --> RELOCATE

Searching using '%RELOCATE%' at the beginning, and found everything I needed except the text above. I then started researching and the best that I could find suggested something using square brackets like  th.description like '[a-zA-Z0-9]RELOCATE%'.  That doesn't work either.  What am I missing or should be doing?

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=fd2244757f6b9bfe16460d274a652dcb). [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Provide the query you used for the search which didn't find the record.

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't support regular expressions. You need an operator [that does that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP)